# Vaadin Designer Attributes and Layers missing in Editor

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-designer

I'm using Vaadin Designer with Eclipse and lately the sidebar with the attributes and layers is missing in the editor of the browser. I get the following error message, but I don't know if it has to do with the problem, because I'm not a developer myself:

OS: Mac OS X 13.2.1 x86_64
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_16) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/522.0
Java: 17.0.6
Eclipse: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product 4.27.0.20230309-1200
Designer: 4.6.21
Error:
Unknown browser message with topic "browserStatus", json: "webSocketReady"
No stacktrace available.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8GZv.png)

I tried to use the Editor in the Chrome Browser to edit a Vaadin 10+ view, but the sidebar with the layers and attributes are missing.

I already dowloaded the latest version of eclipse IDE, installed Vaadin Designer via marketplace  and setup a new project to test it out but the issue still occurs.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which version of Vaadin? Which version of the IDE?

Comment: I tried it in chrome and safari.
The Versions are Java: 17.0.6 Eclipse: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product 4.27.0.20230309-1200 Designer: 4.6.21